# How to support layout for xhdpi and xxhdpi devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing layout problem to support xhdpi and xxhdpi devices. As far as I know, android has no support for layout-xxlarge or layout-xxhdpi. Android use layout-xlarge to support both xhdpi and xxhdpi. For this reason, I am facing problem. Basically problems are two types. One is the top margin issues. Is there any way to set the top margin for both xhdpi and xxhdpi devices. I can't use LayoutParams or ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams. The reason is I am using LinearLayout to define weightSum of children LinearLayout. Inside the children LinearLayout, I am using RelativeLayout for my layout.

Comment: Did you read the official documentation on the subject ? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html Quoting : "Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups [talking about small, normal, large, and xlarge] are deprecated and you should instead use the sw<N>dp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources."

Comment: Yes I have already read the official document. At now i am using two different layout programmatically after checking the device density. It is a different kind of solution though, but whatever it purposes my service

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that as of Android 3.2, the layout-xlarge, large, normal, small are all deprecated, and new identifiers were introduced, which you can find here [Supporting Multiple Screens | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

[**Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

> For the first generation of tablets running Android 3.0, the proper way to declare tablet layouts was to put them in a directory with the xlarge configuration qualifier (for example, res/layout-xlarge/). In order to accommodate other types of tablets and screen sizes—in particular, 7" tablets—Android 3.2 introduces a new way to specify resources for more discrete screen sizes.

Comment: Yes I have already read the official document. At now i am using two different layout programmatically after checking the device density. It is a different kind of solution though, but whatever it purposes my service. Whatever thanks for your suggestion....

Answer (score -1):

You should create dir with needed name like layout-xxhdpi

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Comment: I think layout-xxhdpi does not exist android. drawable-xxhdpi is available not layout-xxhdpi.